# What are some ways to store Tomcat 6 stdout and stderr logs to external server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, logging

Due to compliance issues, there is a need to store all tomcat logs for at least 6 months on a central server.

Is there a way to send the logs to rsyslog server or any other mechanism that will accomplish the task. I tried changing CATALINA_OUT to /var/log/syslog, and it does record it in the file however rsyslog-mysql does not pick it up.

Short of sending the logs to a remote host, what are some ways to move the logs automatically besides using rsync, cron, scp

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1377054) is an interesting thread about your question. If this really leads to a solution is not sure. A working approach is to output to stdout and pipe that to `logger` - but this is not a "clean" solution.

Comment: The linked thread is not related in any way to stdout/stderr. But the `logger` approach is sound and I don't see anything unclean about it. Bonus points would be for somehow redirecting the damn AccessLogValve (localhost_access_log file).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Splunk

http://www.splunk.com

Here is some information about how you can set archive policies:

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/4.2.5/Admin/Setaretirementandarchivingpolicy

I'm not sure what kind of compliance you are trying to meet but Splunk has some great plugins - ex:

SEC
http://www.splunk.com/view/sec-compliance/SP-CAAAGMQ

HIPPA
http://www.splunk.com/view/hipaa-compliance/SP-CAAAGG6

PCI
http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAFHB

Answer (score -1):

Splunk!? 
That thing is *so* expensive.  It's a good Thing, but an expensive one.

What you might get more of a kick out of is something like [Logstash](http://logstash.net/), or [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/)

Logstash will pretty much do exactly what you want. It has an agent that can tail logfiles.

I wonder though.. What would happen if you pointed the catalina.out log entry at a FIFO pipe, then piped that through `logger` (which writes to syslog)

Answer (score -1):

Check out this http://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/monitor-your-cluster-of-tomcat-applications-with-logstash-and-kibana/

- logstash : http://logstash.net/ opensource  tool for managing events and logs
- kibana :   opensource tool for visualizing logs and time-stamped data